# Decorator does not work when function is passed as object in a process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-decorators

I have the following code:

```
@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=2)
def a_func:
  do_somthing

def a_func_thread:
  process = multiprocessing.Process(target=a_func, args=[])
  process.start()
```

What I am seeing is that the decorator works when I call a_func directly.  But when I use it as a target function in a process, the process does not seem to respect decorators at all.  Am I missing something very simple here?

Comment: Can you show a complete, self-contained script that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorator will always work, because decorator is only called when function is defined, and the result of decorator call is then stored as the function name.

```
def decorator(fnc):
    def test():
        print "test"
    return test

@decorator
def foo():
    print "foo"

foo() # will print test
```

At the point of `target=a_func`, in `a_func` is the result of calling the @retry decorator.

Comment: Could you explain the target bit a little more, please?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins you can think of a decorator as a function that is called when function (or class) is created. Whatever the decorator returns is then considered to be that function.

Comment: Does that mean that the function isn't created in the other process?